# SSRS SUM and IIF statement based on Group

Tags: reporting-services, iif

I have a dataset "dsAuditQuestions" which has fields including "Category" and "SuccessCriteriaMet". The latter contains either a "True" or "False" value which I'd like to count as 1 or 0..

I have created a tablix which groups by "Category1".
I'm trying to write an expression in SSRS to calculate the SUM of the 1s for each category.

I've tried many variations but can't get it to work.

=SUM(IIF(Fields!Category.Value="Category1" AND Fields!SuccessCriteriaMet.Value = "True",1,0),"dsAuditQuestions")

Comment: Try removing the dataset name from the SUM

Comment: Hi, Thanks. I've tried removing the dataset name so it now reads.. =SUM(IIF(Fields!Category.Value="Category1" AND Fields!SuccessCriteriaMet.Value = "True",1,0)) but it just gives the response '0' for all categories.

Comment: Some sample data and layout would help

Comment: You probably need to use `Fields!SuccessCriteriaMet.Value = True` without the quotes (or `1`) since you field sounds like a bit or INT rather than CHAR.